# How to link a lib written in D to use it with a program written in C, under Windows, using MinGW GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, d, dmd

I would like to use a library written in D for a C program compilable with MinGW GCC, for Windows. Here are the codes:

**dll.d**

```
extern (C) int dsquare(int n) nothrow
{
    return n * n;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int res = dsquare(6); // Expect '36'
    printf("res = %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

There is [a tutorial on D's site](https://dlang.org/articles/dll-linux.html), but it seems to target only Linux. Indeed, no explanation is given for creating such a dynamic D library for Windows and MinGW users.

[D's documentation](https://wiki.dlang.org/Win32_DLLs_in_D) also says that the `-shared` option should generate a DLL version of the D code, but in my case, it generates an executable, I don't know why.

Also, anything that seems to generate files to be linked targets MVSC formats and nothing seems to be suitable for MinGW GCC compilers.

So, how can I generate a "GCC-friend" DLL with D, so that I can link it to my C program without having to use another compiler, such as GDC or LDC, via `gcc main.c -o main -ldll -L.` (I guess)?

Comment: try using the -shared together with the -o thing to just rename it to .dll. might be the stupid compiler doen't change the extension but still generates the right file. But dmd is so focused on msvc compat I'm not sure it does gcc compat at all.

Answer (score 0):

I attached link with short explanation. Link D onto C is not so straightforward as C to D. Check D.org page here:
https://dlang.org/spec/betterc.html

Comment: While this link might answer the question, you should copy the main points to the answer itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer